# How do i add Data from an array to object in React Native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

** The Following arrays have data that should be stored in data and labels which will then be shown in an app.**
const days[];
const level[];

````
for(var i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
      days.push((data2.Table[i].DayName).slice(0, 3))
      level.push(data2.Table[i].Moisturevalue)


    }

```const data = {
  labels:["mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","mon","Tue"], //willing to update this from harcoded to dynamic 
  datasets: [
    {
      data: days, //Days Contains some numeric data that data should contain 
}]```
````

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to do. If you could provide some dummy data for data2 and provide a sample of your desires result it would be helpful

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I extract the days and values from the API using the for loop now I want to make line chart on the basis of these days and values

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that `data2` is an object and that it has a prop `Table` that is an array. It appears that you want to extract the  that you want to extract DayName (the first 3 characters) and MoistureValue from `data2.Table`. If this is true, here's how I would go about it:

```js
const days = [];
const levels = [];
data2.Table.forEach(dataItem=>{
   //using substring rather than slice makes it clear you are working with a string
   days.push( dataItem.dayName.substring(0,3) )
   levels.push( dataItem.Moisturevalue )
})
```